# What is the root password for Ubuntu on Docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ssh

I am trying to use ssh to connect inside a container with Ubuntu however I need the password.

Comment: If you have an access to the docker host you can simply `docker exec -ti <id> /bin/bash` into it and change whatever you want (just type `passwd`, make sure that the `openssh/opensshd` service is active).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You usually don't ssh into Docker containers: they're usually running only a single process and that process usually isn't an ssh daemon.

If you have access to the host to run Docker commands, you can `docker exec -u root <containerid>` to get a root shell in the container.

Since you can always get a root shell from the host if you really need to, there just isn't a root password, and you can't directly log in as root.  (Also you can't directly **login**(8) to a container and there usually isn't a remote shell service of any sort, so you can't directly log in as anything in any case.)

Comment: I was needing the password because I am trying to use the remote debug of visual studio code for dotnet core through ssh into the container but I did not succeed.

Comment: @PauloLeal You could log in as root as @DavidMaze suggests and then run `passwd` to set the root password.